# Image generated by System.Drawing.Image is 10x larger than original file

Tags: .net, powershell, ffmpeg

I've written a Powershell script that extracts one frame from a dshow capture device using FFmpeg, and then copies the output image from a file to my clipboard:

```
$screenshot = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile((Get-Item -Path $outputFilePath))
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage($screenshot)
$screenshot.Dispose()
```

The original file is a 1MB JPEG, but the image in my clipboard is an 11MB PNG. When I go to paste this file into something like Discord the file size is too large, unless you have Discord Nitro.

Is there any way to avoid this file size inflation while using `[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile()`?

Here's an easy test template:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$screenshot = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile((Get-Item -Path "Path to picture"))
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage($screenshot)
$screenshot.Dispose()
```

Edit 2021/05/13:

Interestingly, it's starting to seem like this is a limitation of copying an image to a clipboard. I decided to dig deeper and see if the image size was increasing when I drew the image with `System.Drawing.Image` or when I pushed it in my clipboard with `System.Windwos.Forms.Clipboard`. If I save the image before putting it my clipboard like so, it retains the original file size, even if I change the extension to png:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$screenshot = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile((Get-Item -Path "C:\Users\gabri\Pictures\FFScreenshots\2021-05-12 19-04-26.845.jpeg"))
$screenshot.Save("C:\Users\gabri\Pictures\FFScreenshots\test.jpeg") # test.png makes no difference
$screenshot.Dispose()
```

So it would seem that the image grows exponentially in size specifically when I push it to my clipboard. I verified this by simply uploading an image to Discord, copying it to my clipboard (click image > Open original > right click and copy result), and uploading it again. Sure enough, the new image pasted from my clipboard was around 10x the size of the original image (1MB vs 12MB). I wondered if this was a "limitation" of Windows so I ran the same test on Ubuntu 20.04. Uploaded an image to Discord, copied the image to my clipboard, and uploaded it again. Once again the image was about 10x larger, though slightly smaller than then when I uploaded the image from my clipboard on my Windows machine (11.4MB VS 12MB). Just to make sure this wasn't limited to Discord, I ran the same test with Gmail in-browser on both operating systems, same result.

Alas, there appears to be something happening when you copy an image to a clipboard that drastically increases file size. One thing's for sure, whatever's happening is definitely over my head.

Comment: Question, does it happen on PS and PS ISE ? I can't test this rn, not on Windows

Comment: It would appear to perform no differently in PS ISE, is there a situation where Powershell code would perform differently across different IDEs?

Comment: When working with `System.Windows.Forms` it behaves different, but i'm not sure if this is something that happens to everyone. i.e. Different resolutions in ISE and normal PS `[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen` and different aspect ratio. But I guess this is not related to that.

Comment: The clipboard `SetImage()` method adds an Image in the **uncompressed** Bitmap format. Depending if the receiving application understands the jpeg format, you may try using the method described in the [Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=net-5.0#remarks), of the MS docs on the Clipboard class, second Note: _"To preserve your data format, add your data as a Byte array to a MemoryStream and pass the MemoryStream to the SetData method."_

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Theo, can't seem to get this working. I think I'm stuck with the way things are, if there was a way to copy and paste images without increasing the size it would be built directly into the OS I would imagine.

The image I'm testing with is 3840x2160, which is larger than the 1920x1080 most people will be dealing with when it comes to pulling frames from capture cards. If push comes to shove, I can add an option to downscale the image during the FFmpeg process.

I should have gained a more complete understanding of how this all worked before asking for help.